# takeown /R not applying to hidden files

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2008, file-permissions, batch-file

I'm running a batch command to take ownership of a set of user folders and I'm finding that the ownership is not being pushed down to hidden files, such as ~normal.dot
I'm using the following command: 
`takeown /R /A /D Y /F D:\folderpath\username`
I don't see errors in the output, but when I try to robocopy that directory, I get access denied on such files.
I find that I have to manually go to file properties > Security > Advanced > Edit (server 2008) > Replace all existing inheritable permissions on all descendants with inhabitable permissions from this object.
Is there a way to make sure that I can move the folder after I've taken ownership of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you took ownership with Takeown, but didn't give yourself read/write permissions (which is why you had to edit them via the GUI afterwards).

To do that from the command line you'd use [`icacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) after using `takeown`.

Something to the effect of `icacls <directory name> /grant <your username>:F /t`.

Comment: After running the takeown command with the /A switch, administrators are automatically added to the ACL of the folder, just not the hidden files.  Do I still need to run the icacls command?

Comment: /A makes the Administrators group the owner instead of you.  Remember, just because you own it doesn't mean you have write permissions. :)

Comment: Sorry to bug again, however even after running icacls, I still received access is denied on hidden files that begin with ~.  Any ideas?

Comment: Thank *god* for this answer!!! I've been pulling my hair out for hours trying to figure out how I can be the owner, yet have no access to delete a file!  Sure enough, I didn't have read/write permissions and once I granted them, the file went the way of the dodo! Thanks again for this answer!!