# Windows 10 with Bitlocker: Data recovery unable to read files

Tags: windows-10, encryption, data-recovery, bitlocker

I am trying to backup some data out of a bootlooping/non starting Windows 10 system.

The drives are encrypted with BitLocker and unlocking with the recovery key worked. I can browse e.g. the C: drive just fine and see all folders and file names. Opening of files within the users document folder e.g. with notepad fails with a "Permission denied" error. Writing new files works flawlessly. Displaying the owner of the files with dir /Q shows "..." as the Owner.

Opening a file with notepad shows an error message of a rather long username string.

Is there a quick way to change read permissions or work as the user correctly (the password is known and I have entered it right after entering the BitLocker recovery key)?

Comment: The fact you are getting permissions errors for folders and files contained within a user's profile is perfectly normal, you will have to take ownership of the root folder, and apply the proper permissions to it's contents.  Since you don't have any permissions, since the files are from another Windows installation, you cannot simply grant yourself read permissions.  Taking ownership of the files, then granting those permissions, is your only solution.  This will permanently change the ownership of those files.

Comment: I am fine with that - but how can I take ownership from within the recovery console?

Comment: I tried with `takedown /f file.ext` and `icacls file.ext /grant "NT-AUTHORITY/SYSTEM":(f) /t` according to https://superuser.com/questions/1414910/understanding-how-to-use-icals-takeown-to-make-changes-and-reset-in-windows-10

Both commands went through successfully but I am still unable to open the file e.g. in notepad or copy it to an external drive - the error is still "Access denied".

Comment: You said nothing of being limited to the recovery console.  You indicated you were able to successfully mount the encrypted volume in Windows.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Sorry for being unprecise. Windows is not starting at all (all reparis/rollbacks) failed, so I am constraint to the recovery console for now after unlocking with the recovery key.

Comment: You indicated you could browse the files.  I assumed perhaps incorrectly you had mounted the drive to a working installation of Windows.